# The `+` in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am new in ruby, and I am reading the `Progamming Ruby` and following its examples.

This is the codes which teach the `Inheritance and Messages`:

```
class Song
  def initialize(name, artist, duration)
    @name=name;
    @artist=artist;
    @duration=duration;
  end

  def to_s
    "Song:#@name \t#@artist\t#@duration"
  end
end

class KaraokeSong < Song
  def initialize(name, artist, duration, lyrics)
    super(name, artist, duration);
    @lyrics=lyrics;
  end

  def to_s
    super + "[#@lyrics]";
  end
end

song=KaraokeSong.new("There for me", "Sarah", 2320, "There for me, every time I've been away...")
puts song.to_s
```

This codes works fine.

However I found that if I change the `to_s` of `KaraokeSong` to this(Note there is no space between the `+` and the `"[#@lyrics]"`):

```
  def to_s
    super +"[#@lyrics]";
  end
```

I will get the error:

> in `to_s': undefined method`+@' for "[There for me, every time I've
>   been away...]":String (NoMethodError)

But then I make a test:

```
name="kk"
puts name +"sfds"
```

This codes does not throw any errors.

What's the problem?

BTW, I am using `ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [x64-mingw32]`

Comment: That's the unary plus operator. Your second example uses the binary plus operator, which is a function of two variables.

Comment: FYI you don't need `;` as a statement terminator in Ruby :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing the method call there on the `String`. Previously, you're doing effectively this:

`super.+(string)`

Now, you're doing this `super(+string)`. The `+@` method isn't defined on String (it's defined on numbers though, and just returns a positive number), and that's why you're seeing this error.